# Python - Error at equals sign for no reason?

Tags: python

I'm using eval and pybrain to make neural networks. Here's it stripped down. Using python 3.6

```
    from pybrain import *

    numnn = 100

    eval("neuralNetwork" + chr(numnn) + " = buildNetwork(2, 3, 1, bias=True)")
```

Comment: You should show what is happening.

Comment: what's the error code you are getting when you run this?

Comment: What is the error you see?

Answer (score 3):

`eval` evaluates expressions.  Assignment in Python is not an expression, it's a statement.

But you don't need this anyway.  Make a list or dict to hold all of your values.